# Python: Write to next empty line

Tags: python

I'm trying to write the output of something that is being done over three big iterations and each time I'm opening and closing the outfile. Counters get reset and things like this after the iterations and I'm a massive newb and would struggle to work around this with the shoddy code I've written. So even if it's slower I'd like change the way it is being output.

Currently for the output it's just rewriting over the first line so I have only the output of the last run of the program. (tau, output are variables given values in the iterations above in the code)

```
with open(fileName + '.autocorrelate', "w") as outfile:
    outfile.writelines('{0}     {1}{2}'.format(tau, output, '\n'))
```

I was wondering if there are any quick ways to get python to check for the first empty line when it opens a file and write the new line there?

Comment: small stylistic suggestion: you can write `outfile.writelines('{0}     {1}\n'.format(tau, output))`, no need to supply `\n` separately.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open with "a" instead of "w" will write at the end of the file. That's the way to not overwrite.

Comment: This doesn't necessarily find the first empty line and write there (which would be quite difficult with a simple ascii file).  It does however, write after the last line, which is what the question was really asking...

Answer (score 1):

If you open your file in append mode : `"a"` instead of "`w`", you will be able to write a new line at the end of your file.

Answer (score 0):

You do do something like that to keep a reference (line number) to every empty line in a file

```
# Get file contents
fd = open(file)
contents = fd.readlines()
fd.close()

empty_line = []
i = 0

# find empty line
for line in contents:
    if line == "":
       empty_line.append(i)
    i+=1
```